# NodeJS listen to signal from bash script on some event

Tags: node.js

Is there any way to nodejs listening for some way of signal that is generated by a bash script on some event random in time?

How can I generate that signal in bash script and  listening on nodejs?

Any help is welcome
Regards

Answer (score 5):

A node.js process can listen for any POSIX signal. <s>Personally, I use the SIGUSR1 event.</s> Use `SIGUSR2`.

See http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/process.html#signal_Events for more info.

Comment: It looks like, at least in node.js 0.12, `SIGUSR1 is reserved by node.js to start the debugger. It's possible to install a listener but that won't stop the debugger from starting.`. Might be better to use `SIGUSR2`

Comment: Oh, lord. 3 years ago. Such a babe, I was. Yeah, `SIGUSR2` all the way.

Answer (score 2):

use [kill](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/kill-invocation.html#kill-invocation) command to send signal to your node.js script (pid is [process.pid](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/process.html#process.pid))
use `process.on([SIGNALNAME], ... )` event handler to listen for signal in your script.

Answer (score 0):

You can run the bash script as a [child process](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/child_processes.html) and capture the output via child.stdout or child.stderr